# How to build a chrome extension to read shopping carts from Amazon, Ebay.. etc?

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-chrome-extension, e-commerce, shopping-cart

How can I build a chrome extension to read stores' shopping cart data?

Let me explain my idea,

I want a user to install my chrome extension, and when he visits Amazon, Ebay,... etc, my extension will show up for him at a specific place. Then when he add an item to the store's shopping cart, the item will be added to my extension shopping cart too.

**Example of extensions:** MyUs Shopping Chrome Extension, DHL, Clickapporter... etc

Any idea about the way it can be implemented?

**UPDATE**

I want to read the data because my idea is a shopping cart extension that collects items from many websites to my cart, then deliver them to the user after they pay.

Comment: This sounds like a privacy nightmare. What are you planning to do with the data?

Comment: The question is not really answerable now. You need to break down the problem into smaller specific parts.

Comment: @Andy I need the data to create a shopping cart to collects the items and deliver them to the user.

Comment: But isn't that what the existing shopping carts do?

Comment: @Andy yes, but my idea is collecting items from many websites into one cart which is mine, then deliver the items to the user easily.

Comment: I've got to be honest with you - that sounds like a terrible idea.